# How can I stop resharper replacing correct code?

Tags: vb.net, resharper

I have a project that is VB.Net and C# and resharper installed in our VS2012 environment.

Resharper is pretty cool most of the time, but it has some really annoying behaviour in VB.Net where it replaces normal, correct code with rubbish.

For example, if I type in "Select Case" it'll replace it with "[Select] CaseInsensitiveComparer "

[image]

I actually prefer the native VB.Net intellisense to the resharper one. How do I turn this off?

Mostly I want to reclaim the use of my `SPACE` key as a space. Not as `accept resharper's suggestion`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem. While we work on it, there are several ways to work around it.

1. ReSharper | Options -> Environment | IntelliSense | Completing Characters -> turn off "Complete on space". ReSharper wouldn't complete on space, but would still complete on other characters.
2. ReSharper | Options -> Environment | IntelliSense | Autopopup ->  VB.NET -> set everything to "Display but do not preselect". This way ReSharper would only complete when you press Tab or Ctrl+Enter.
3. ReSharper | Options -> Environment | IntelliSense | General -> set Limited ReSharper IntelliSense and turn off VB.NET. This would completely turn off ReSharper IntelliSense and restore Visual Studio's one for VB.NET. Other ReSharper features (highlightings, refactorings and so on) would still work.

Comment: Thank you. Amazing product by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

That should be configuration under Resharper's Context Actions  ( Resharper Options -> Code Editing -> Visual Basic.Net -> Context Actions) as [explained here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__Visual_Basic__NET__Context_Actions.html)

Comment: Thanks, that has a list of Context Actions (I'd found and looked through them already). But none of them are the `Select Case` one and I think I mostly want it to stop interpreting my `space` key as anything other than a space...